# What does solid in border-style:solid mean? CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an exam tomorrow and it's about CSS, we have always had border-style:solid; but I don't really know what it exactly does. It sure shows a border but why is it called "solid"? W3S doesn't really give me the answer...

Does solid mean e.g. the paraghraph's border is not movable?

Or does it mean the border's size cant change?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about reading docs.

Comment: Please refer to the official documentation. Downvote.

Comment: It is a clarification of the meaning of the word in the context of documentation. Let it live

Answer (score 4):

It is a **solid** continuous line in one piece as opposed to a dashed or dotted line which are composed of many separate lines or dots. The width of the line is  a separate property and it can vary.

Comment: @tommy ringer -  hope the exam went OK, did the extra info help?

Answer (score 3):

**SOLID** means displaying a single, straight, solid line.

Other possible values are;

**DOTTED**: Displaying a series of rounded dots.

**DASHED**: Displaying a series of short square-ended dashes or line segments.

**See full details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style**

Answer (score 1):

Border style changes how the border looks. Solid means there are no holes in the border.

[All the different types of border styles.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-style)